# Haskell and the 'loop' with guard

Tags: haskell, guard

I've problem with Haskell. I've got a simple code:

```
petla szerokosc wysokosc pozycje = do
let plansza_x = oznacz_pola_dookola_jako_miejsca_na_skarby_wiele 
            pozycje
        (utworz_plansze pozycje szerokosc wysokosc) 
        szerokosc
 let x = make_list $ zlicz_x plansza_x
 guard ((sprawdz_kombinacje2 plansza_x pozycje (head x) szerokosc wysokosc) == True)
 x
```

The parameters are good, but the GHCI returns my something strange.
function `make_list` returns the list of Strings, for example: `[['_','_'],['*','_'],['_','*'],['*','*']]`.

I want the `loop` get the first element of this list, paste it as an argument into the `sprawdz_kombinacje2`. If that function return `False` it will be get net element from the list. Otherwise the function `petla` should return the String, for example: `['_','*']`.

The problem: when I run this function in GHCI, it returns me empty list, but it shouldn't:

```
*Main> petla 2 2 [(1,1,1)]
[]
```

But, when I added `return` to the last line:

```
petla szerokosc wysokosc pozycje = do
let plansza_x = oznacz_pola_dookola_jako_miejsca_na_skarby_wiele 
            pozycje
        (utworz_plansze pozycje szerokosc wysokosc) 
        szerokosc
 let x = make_list $ zlicz_x plansza_x
 guard ((sprawdz_kombinacje2 plansza_x pozycje (head x) szerokosc wysokosc) == True)
 return x
```

and I compiled it, and run this function with the same arguments like before, the GHCI returns me:

```
*Main> petla 2 2 [(1,1,1)]

<interactive>:1:0:
    Ambiguous type variable `m' in the constraint:
      `Control.Monad.MonadPlus m'
         arising from a use of `petla' at <interactive>:1:0-18
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

Comment: Your code doesn't run. I'd try to fix it, but the variable names are putting me off. You have a much better chance of getting a response if your names are (1) shorter and (2) in English.

Comment: Also please clarify exactly what it is you are asking and define the functions that you haven't shown code for that aren't standard functions.

Comment: For now, I'll say that I don't think you understand what `return` means in a functional language such as Haskell.

Answer (score 8):

GHC and GHCi were, as I'm sure you know, written in Glasgow. Its first several public releases only accepted code written in Scots. For example, using the RWS monad looked like:

```
import Guide.Monad.RWS

ensaumple :: RWS Int [Int] Int ()
ensaumple = dae
  env <- aks
  s   <- git
  lat s' = s + env
  pit s'
  clype [s']
```

The authors had quite the challenging time localizing it to English. So I'm quite certain it will be some years before GHC is able to handle code in Polish. Przepraszam :(

Comment: I'm a little bit sad that my troll answer has more upvotes than Daniel's real answer. Also a little bit happy.

Comment: Hmm, weren't hierarchical modules only added after the port to English?

Answer (score 5):

The message from ghci,

```
*Main> petla 2 2 [(1,1,1)]

<interactive>:1:0:
    Ambiguous type variable `m' in the constraint:
      `Control.Monad.MonadPlus m'
         arising from a use of `petla' at <interactive>:1:0-18
    Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

means that the expression `petla 2 2 [(1,1,1)]` has the inferred type

```
MonadPlus m => m sometype
```

The `MonadPlus` constraint on `m` comes from the use of `guard`. But ghci has no way to know which instance of `MonadPlus` it should use here. In programmes, that can usually be inferred from the calling context, but at the ghci prompt, there is no calling context. Hence you have to tell ghci which `MonadPlus` instance to use. You can do that by providing a type signature for `petla` in the file where it is defined (or, if it's defined at the prompt, by giving a type signature there along with the definition), or by providing a type signature for the expression entered at the ghci prompt, for example

```
ghci> petla 2 2 [(1,1,1)] :: [sometype]
```

(replace `sometype` with an appropriate monomorphic type; if the result of `make_list` is, as indicated by the post, `[[String]]`, that would replace `sometype` in the signature).